# Updating Nikon DSLR firmware, do I need to install older missed updates?

Tags: nikon, firmware, upgrade

When updating a Nikon DSLR firmware, do I need to install older missed updates before installing the latest version?

Also where can I find the changelog (fixes/added feauters) for all previous versions so I could determine whether I need to update or not?

Comment: Be careful with any firmware "upgrade".  I'd leave the firmware alone unless I knew of a specific problem that I care about was fixed in the newer version.  All changes include risk.  Make sure the expected advantage outweighs the likely risk before blindly messing with something that is basically working.  *If it ain't broke, don't fix it!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need to install previous updates if installing a newer one, and on the camera settings it's possible to check the firmware version by doing the following: 
1. Enter Setup Menu
2. Click on Firmware Settings option

This link has the latest firmwares available for Nikon cameras: https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13783/~/current-firmware-downloads-available-for-nikon-products

If I'm correct, prior to downloading, instructions to applying it are given.

P.S. Always check what has changed on new firmware, as other people have said, sometimes it comes with some pretty bad bugs or reduced functionality(such as not having support for third party batteries).

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you have to upgrade to a required level! You will have to check out the release nose of the latest firmware, it will tell you whether it is a cumulative update or you need to install a previous firmware first.

Been there, done this.

(Just a quick note: installing the latest firmware is sometimes not beneficial. I resisted to install a newer firmware because reportedly the autofocus got much slower in low-light condition, and since I was happy with the focus quality, I have not installed the latest version.)